# how to get the basename of complicated files

Tags: shell

Here is an example of file path:

```
/isf/GCM/VPfig/Aas/AR/ClCo el Doma Republic/VMN CRTro.txt
```

What I want to get is the file basename:

```
VMN CRTro.txt
```

So I try the following:

```
echo /isf/GCM/VPfig/Aas/AR/ClCo el Doma Republic/VMN CRTro.txt | sed s'/\// /g' | awk '{print $NF}'
CRTro.txt     <-- not as expected
```

Or

```
basename  /isf/GCM/VPfig/Aas/AR/ClCo el Doma Republic/VMN CRTro.txt
basename: extra operand `Doma'
Try `basename --help' for more information.     <-- basename cant handle spaces
```

What the best way to get the basename of a file with spaces in it?

Comment: what about basename  "/isf/GCM/VPfig/Aas/AR/ClCo el Doma Republic/VMN CRTro.txt"

Comment: yes its so simple , I am really stupid!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just quote your path

```
basename  "/isf/GCM/VPfig/Aas/AR/ClCo el Doma Republic/VMN CRTro.txt"
```

Comment: Surely single quotes would be safer here than double quotes. Otherwise, if the filename includes anything that the shell can expand, the shell will perform that expansion, which will not be the desired result.

Answer (score 11):

The core of the issue is quoting. Without quotes, it's treating the file name as multiple arguments to `basename`.
If the path is hard set, and not a variable, then rob's answer is good. But if this is part of a script, where a variable is being used, you have 2 good solutions:

```
$ filepath="/isf/GCM/VPfig/Aas/AR/ClCo el Doma Republic/VMN CRTro.txt"
$ basename "$filepath"
VMN CRTro.txt
```

However `basename` is an external utility, and not part of bash. There is an alternative solution built into bash:

```
$ filepath="/isf/GCM/VPfig/Aas/AR/ClCo el Doma Republic/VMN CRTro.txt"
$ echo "${filepath##*/}"
VMN CRTro.txt
```

The `${filepath##*/}` tells bash to perform the glob `*/`, which matches as many characters as possible followed by a `/`, and then strip it out.

Comment: The usual warning about `basename` vs `${var##*/}`: it doesn't work properly for `path/to/dir/` or `/`. You'd want `basename -- "$filepath"` (for paths that start with `-`).

Answer (score 1):

Both the answers here are more than sufficient - though I would personally do as Patrick suggests and use `${var##*/}`. Still, just for fun:

```
IFS=/ ; set -f
set -- ${0+/isf/GCM/VPfig/Aas/AR/ClCo el Doma Republic/VMN CRTro.txt}
for p do i=$((i+1))
    printf "arg#$i:\t%s\n" "${p:-/}"
done
echo now shift out...
shift $(($#-1))
printf 'arg#1:\t%s\n' "$1"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
arg#1:  /
arg#2:  isf
arg#3:  GCM
arg#4:  VPfig
arg#5:  Aas
arg#6:  AR
arg#7:  ClCo el Doma Republic
arg#8:  VMN CRTro.txt
now shift out...
arg#1:  VMN CRTro.txt
```

You don't have to worry about `$IFS` eating up your variable evaluations if you set it properly. You can even use it to your advantage.

Comment: Note that the above doesn't work in `bash` (except in `sh` emulation) and you get an odd behaviour with `mksh`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I fixed it for `bash` - I guess it doesn't like variable declarations against builtins. Or maybe it doesn't persist them. Anyway, just added a semicolon. I don't have `mksh` though - I should probably install it.

Comment: It only worked because `set` is a _special_ builtin. For `mksh`, see http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.os.miros.mksh/424

Comment: @StephaneChezales - I just installed it and I see what you mean - you get 7 arguments because the lone / is completely evaluated away. So $1 becomes *isf* - weird. Anyway, it does work, but it bothers me. 16 minutes ago huh? As always, thank you.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - about the [`bash` thing](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=352). Also, while I've got your ear, in a manner of speaking, any idea what happens after [interpretation approved?](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=654) - it's added to the next version maybe?